# Using recursion and a structure to return multiple sets of values

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, return-value

As implied in the question, I was wondering if it is possible to return multiple sets of data using recursion and structures. In my program can successfully return two values by populating a structure and returning that value, but now I want to repopulate the content of that structure when the function recursively calls itself.

```
/* function prints all the nodes which contain the addresses in a given range [x -- y] */
struct baseBound check_addr(struct Node *root, int x, int y) {
    struct baseBound addrData;
    if(NULL == root) {
        return addrData;
    }
    if(x < root->startAddr)
        check_addr(root->left, x, y);
    if(root->startAddr <= x  && y <= root->endAddr) {
        addrData.base = root->startAddr;
        addrData.bound = root->endAddr;
        check_addr(root->left, x, y);
        if(root->startAddr == x && y < root->endAddr)
             check_addr(root->right, x, y);
    }
    if(x > root->startAddr)
        check_addr(root->right, x, y);

    return addrData;
}

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main() {
    struct Node *root = NULL;
    struct baseBound addrData;

    root = insert(root, 0x40, 0x238);
    root = insert(root, 0x238, 0x254);
    root = insert(root, 0x0, 0x838);
    root = insert(root, 0x200db8, 0x201018);
    root = insert(root, 0x200dc8, 0x200fb8);
    root = insert(root, 0x254, 0x298);
    root = insert(root, 0x6f4, 0x730);
    root = insert(root, 0x0, 0x0);
    root = insert(root, 0x200db8, 0x201000);

    printf("Postorder traversal of the constructed AVL tree is \n");
    postOrder(root);
    printf("\n");

    addrData = check_addr(root, 0x238, 0x254);
    printf("%x >> %x\n", addrData.base, addrData.bound);
    return 0;
}
```

Above are two portions of the code, the first function traverses a AVL tree to find nodes where the input data fits between. In the main function the AVL tree is created in a postOrdered fashion, and the check_addr function is called with two ints as parameters. Based off the tree and input values, there should be two sets of data, as check_addr is recursively called, but when using the structure return method this is not the case.

Before posting here I did search online for a similar question, but could not find anything related. Hopefully someone here can provide some assistance. Thank you!

Comment: _"this is not the case."_ So, what **is** the case? What output do you get instead of the one you want?

Comment: I only get one value output instead of two. For example, the values chosen in the main function (0x238, 0x254) fall under two nodes of the tree: 0x0 - 0x838 and 0x238 - 0x254. When the program is run, the output will 0x0 - 0x838, bypassing the second iteration through the function

Comment: The opening four lines of the first function are a disaster. If the incoming data is a null pointer, you return an uninitialized structure?  Not good!

Comment: to be honest, I didn't like that either, but I can't figure out what to return instead...

Comment: At the minimum, you need to return a valid object that isn't UB to read... You could zero it out, for instance, if an all-0 object is not ambiguous with a valid return. An alternative is to assign to an object passed by-pointer by the user, and have your function return a boolean indicating whether it assigned that object or not. Then the user knows whether it was updated, i.e. whether it's valid to read if they passed an uninitialised one. (Of course, in the latter case, your function should ensure it assigns all fields.)